# Resize partition of Windows 7 running on VirtualBox with dynamically allocated storage

Tags: windows-7, virtualbox, gparted, vdi

I run Windows 7 inside VirtualBox.

I resized the disk of Windows 7 from 25 GB to 50 GB:

```
VBoxManage modifyhd Windows\ 7\ Pro.vdi --resize 50000
0%...10%...20%...30%...40%...50%...60%...70%...80%...90%...100%
```

[image: VirtualBox size]

**PROBLEM:** I can' grow the partition, neither with Windows 7 itself nor with GParted:

[image: Disk management]

[image: GParted]

It looks like VirtualBox does not tell the client OS about the new size.
What additional step is necessary?

Comment: there shouldn't be anything else required, although I have had better luck with gparted than right in windows. does your VM with that disk have any snapshots? resizing does not support disks with snapshots.

Comment: The command line tool worked for me. I could then extend the partition inside in Windows.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

You can only resize disks if they are not part of a VM that uses snapshots.

If you are using snapshots,  you can easily clone the state to a new VM and hard disk, and resize that one. VirtualBox 4 now supports cloning from the GUI, so it's super easy.

[VBoxManage - modifyhd](http://www.virtualbox.org/manual/ch08.html#vboxmanage-modifyvdi)

Here's a helpful walk through of the whole process, [Resize and Expand a Virtualbox Hard Drive and Media in 4 Steps](http://justintung.com/2011/01/06/resize-and-expand-a-virtualbox-hard-drive-and-media-made-easy/)

Comment: as Ryan said, my VM had snapshots and I couldn't extend the partition in Windows. I ended up cloning the VM (not just the disk). See command "vboxmanage clonevm". The clone contained only the current state (no snapshots), so I was able to extend the partition.

Comment: That works! Note: After cloning and resizing the disk, open the VM's settings, remove the former disk and add the new one.

Comment: Also it seems to not be available for VMDK disk images

Answer (score 0):

For Windows host:

```
#command - give Windows direct path in order to use vboxmanage in any folder directly
PATH=%PATH%;C:\Program Files\Oracle\VirtualBox
#command - resize vdi, size in MB (75GB below), go to vdi folder first
VBoxmanage modifyhd [%vdiname].vdi --resize 75000
#comment - for Windows VM use some tool, e.g., partitionwizard free, to resize inside VM, profit
```

This is what I use, and it works for me.