# Failure to resize a virtualbox volume

Tags: virtualbox, virtual-machine

I want to increase the size of my virtual machine. Having read these

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11659005/how-to-resize-a-virtualbox-vmdk-file

[How to change fixed size VDI with modifyhd command in Windows?](https://superuser.com/questions/716649/how-to-change-fixed-size-vdi-with-modifyhd-command-in-windows/717409)

I cloned the vmdk file into vdi.
However, when using

```
VBoxManage.exe modifyhd cloned.vdi --resize 102400
```

I received the error message

```
VBoxManage.exe: error: Could not find file for the medium 'C:\Program Files\Oracle\VirtualBox\cloned.vdi' (VERR_FILE_NOT_FOUND)
VBoxManage.exe: error: Details: code VBOX_E_FILE_ERROR (0x80bb0004), component MediumWrap, interface IMedium, callee IUnknown
VBoxManage.exe: error: Context: "OpenMedium(Bstr(pszFilenameOrUuid).raw(), enmDevType, enmAccessMode, fForceNewUuidOnOpen, pMedium.asOutParam())" at line 179 of file VBoxManageDisk.cpp
```

How should I proceed?

Comment: is the location of cloned.vdi indeed `C:\Program Files\Oracle\VirtualBox\cloned.vdi` or is that file stored somewhere else? If the latter, you need to supply the full path of the file and use quotes, eg `vboxmanage.exe modifyhd "c:\temp\cloned.vdi" --resize 102400`. Do note, that by default your vdi is stored in `%appdata%\VirtualBox\...` or something.

Comment: Thanks, but the location is indeed `C:\Program Files\Oracle\VirtualBox\`
I created the temporary .vdi file there for ease of use.

Comment: How did you clone the file and did you move it afterwards? Copying will not work, given that each vdi  needs to be registered with VirtualBox.

Comment: Indeed, that was my problem - copying the file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should do the following instead:

```
VBoxManage.exe modifyhd "%UserProfile%\VirtualBox VMs\<VM name>\<VM name>.vdi" --resize 102400
```

- `%UserProfile%` is `C:\Users\<name>`
- Replace `<VM name>` with the name of your virtual machine.

Comment: Thanks!
I wonder why did that work when my attempt did not.
Why is the location of the vdi important?

Comment: Because the default location is where `VBoxManage.exe` is located.