# Adjusting Ubuntu filesystem to make use of enlarged partitions

Tags: ubuntu, virtualbox, partitioning, virtual-machine, filesystems

I have increased the size of the extended and logical partitions in my Ubuntu VM as described here: [Adding free unpartitioned space to the main Ubuntu partition](https://superuser.com/questions/1303014/adding-free-unpartitioned-space-to-the-main-ubuntu-partition)

Now I want to add these new sectors to my current file system.
My disk filesystems are (as seen by using `df -h` ):

```
Filesystem                    Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
udev                          2.0G     0  2.0G   0% /dev
tmpfs                         396M  8.1M  388M   3% /run
/dev/mapper/vagrant--vg-root   38G   14G   23G  37% /
tmpfs                         2.0G     0  2.0G   0% /dev/shm
tmpfs                         5.0M     0  5.0M   0% /run/lock
tmpfs                         2.0G     0  2.0G   0% /sys/fs/cgroup
/dev/sda1                     472M   48M  401M  11% /boot
vagrant                       477G  399G   78G  84% /vagrant
shared_directory              477G  399G   78G  84% /shared_directory
tmpfs                         396M     0  396M   0% /run/user/1000
```

The file system that I need to increase in size in order to make use of this space is  `/dev/mapper/vagrant--vg-root`.

The corresponding devices are sda2 and sda5

```
sudo fdisk /dev/sda <<< "p"

Device     Boot   Start       End   Sectors   Size Id Type
/dev/sda1  *       2048    999423    997376   487M 83 Linux
/dev/sda2       1001470 230195199 229193730 109.3G  5 Extended
/dev/sda5       1001472 230195199 229193728 109.3G 83 Linux
```

I tried using resize2fs on these, but with no effect:

```
vagrant@dsvm:~$ sudo resize2fs /dev/mapper/vagrant--vg-root
resize2fs 1.42.13 (17-May-2015)
The filesystem is already 10097664 (4k) blocks long.  Nothing to do!


vagrant@dsvm:~$ sudo resize2fs /dev/mapper/vagrant--vg-root 26214400
resize2fs 1.42.13 (17-May-2015)
The containing partition (or device) is only 10097664 (4k) blocks.
You requested a new size of 26214400 blocks.


vagrant@dsvm:~$ sudo resize2fs /dev/sda2
resize2fs 1.42.13 (17-May-2015)
resize2fs: Attempt to read block from filesystem resulted in short read while trying to open /dev/sda2
Couldn't find valid filesystem superblock.


vagrant@dsvm:~$ sudo resize2fs /dev/sda5
resize2fs 1.42.13 (17-May-2015)
resize2fs: Device or resource busy while trying to open /dev/sda5
Couldn't find valid filesystem superblock.
```

What should I do to incorporate this space into my filesystem?

---

As per the request in the comments, the results of pvdisplay and lvdisplay after performing the suggested actions.

pvdisplay

```
  --- Physical volume ---
  PV Name               /dev/sda5
  VG Name               vagrant-vg
  PV Size               109.29 GiB / not usable 2.00 MiB
  Allocatable           yes
  PE Size               4.00 MiB
  Total PE              27977
  Free PE               9861
  Allocated PE          18116
  PV UUID               rsXeaK-LWoy-XJGD-ZfCK-BjFM-3zvn-nqMD14
```

lvdisplay

```
  --- Logical volume ---
  LV Path                /dev/vagrant-vg/root
  LV Name                root
  VG Name                vagrant-vg
  LV UUID                zkQ8lz-Ghpb-gCGi-WO5Y-m7Ga-JUeH-8hy5Ds
  LV Write Access        read/write
  LV Creation host, time vagrant, 2017-10-27 20:31:10 +0000
  LV Status              available
  # open                 1
  LV Size                69.77 GiB
  Current LE             17860
  Segments               2
  Allocation             inherit
  Read ahead sectors     auto
  - currently set to     256
  Block device           252:0
```

Comment: Thanks for following me on this saga ;)
For `sudo lvextend -l  /dev/mapper/vagrant--vg-root`
I get `New size of 0 not permitted`

Comment: Curiously /dev/sda5's type was `Linux LVM` before I deleted it and rewrote it, now its type is `Linux`.
Should I be worried?

Comment: Linux doesn't mind too much about partition types... but it would be worth setting it back properly (use `fdisk` --> `t` --> `8e` - I updated the other answer)

Comment: Sorry, `sudo lvextend -l  100%FREE /dev/mapper/vagrant--vg-root` was what I used (and got that message), I just incorrectly copied it here at first. (I get a command parsing error if I input the command without 100%FREE)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As the partition size has changed, you'll need to update the size of the Physical Volume:

```
pvresize /dev/sda5
```

This should output a value that is approximately the same size as the partition.

Then, resize the Logical Volume:

```
lvresize -l +100%FREE /dev/mapper/vagrant--vg-root
```

If the filesystem is not mounted, you should do a full filesystem check: (you can probably skip this)

```
e2fsck -f /dev/mapper/vagrant--vg-root
```

And finally resize the filesystem:

```
resize2fs /dev/mapper/vagrant--vg-root
```

Comment: For `pvresize /dev/mapper/vagrant--vg-root` I got
`Failed to find physical volume "/dev/vagrant-vg/root".`

So I tried a physical volume instead:
`pvresize /dev/sda5`
I got
`  Physical volume "/dev/sda5" changed
  1 physical volume(s) resized / 0 physical volume(s) not resized`
I continued as per your instructions from that point and it worked - the size was indeed increased!
`df -h` yielded: 
`/dev/mapper/vagrant--vg-root   69G   14G   53G  20% /`

Although I wonder why I got only 69G as the size of /dev/sda2 and /dev/sda2 is 109.3G ...

Comment: Regarding the 69GB vs 109GB... that sounds odd.. can you run `pvdisplay` and `lvdisplay`  and post the output in your question?

Comment: Gladly!

(Added to original question as space is insufficient)

Comment: I managed to drop a `+` from the command... specifying `100%FREE` will set the size of the logical volume to the free space (you had ~70GiB free)... we actually wanted `+100%FREE` to _extend_ the lv by 100% of the free space.

Comment: I get `WARNING: Reducing active and open logical volume to 38.52 GiB
  THIS MAY DESTROY YOUR DATA (filesystem etc.)`

I'm not scared, I have a clone!
[y]
`Size of logical volume vagrant-vg/root changed from 69.77 GiB (17860 extents) to 38.52 GiB (9861 extents).
  Logical volume root successfully resized.`

I proceed to `resize2fs /dev/mapper/vagrant--vg-root`
I get `Filesystem at /dev/mapper/vagrant--vg-root is mounted on /; on-line resizing required
resize2fs: On-line shrinking not supported`

df -h:

`/dev/mapper/vagrant--vg-root   69G   20G   47G  30% /`

Comment: `lvresize -l +100%FREE /dev/mapper/vagrant--vg-root` should not make it smaller...? did you miss the `+` again? (That volume is quite possibly now broken, so it would be worth reverting to the clone).

Comment: Tried it from the clone with the "+":
` Size of logical volume vagrant-vg/root changed from 69.77 GiB (17860 extents) to 108.29 GiB (27721 extents).
  Logical volume root successfully resized.`

` resize2fs /dev/mapper/vagrant--vg-root
resize2fs 1.42.13 (17-May-2015)
Filesystem at /dev/mapper/vagrant--vg-root is mounted on /; on-line resizing required
old_desc_blocks = 5, new_desc_blocks = 7
The filesystem on /dev/mapper/vagrant--vg-root is now 28386304 (4k) blocks long.`

df -h :
`/dev/mapper/vagrant--vg-root  107G   14G   89G  13% /`

Success! 
Thank you very much :)